# Python multiple functions with the same decorator execute in main

Tags: python, decorator

I created a decorator to walk through directories for several functions to do some file operations. Every time when more than one functions with the decorator in the script, only the first one will execute.

```
import os
import re
import sys


def oswalk_deco(func):
    def wrapper(filename, *args):
        subdirs = [os.path.abspath(x[0]) for x in os.walk(target_dir)]
        subdirs.remove(os.path.abspath(target_dir))
        for dir in subdirs:
            os.chdir(dir)
            for item in os.listdir('.'):
                p = re.match(filename, item)
                if isinstance(p, re.Match):
                    match = p.group()
                    func(match, *args)
    return wrapper


def str2uni(string):
    if isinstance(string, str):
        return string.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
    else:
        print('Function "str2uni(string)" only accept strings.')
        exit()


@oswalk_deco
def sub_string(filename, regex, substr):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        content = re.sub(regex, substr, content)
        file.write(content)


@oswalk_deco
def regex_print(filename, string):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        relist = re.findall(string, content)

    if filename[0] == 'u':
        print({str2uni(f'\\u{filename[1:-4]}'): relist})
    elif isinstance(re.match(r'code\d{2}-u.+', filename), re.Match):
        print({str2uni(f'\\{re.search("u[0-9a-z]{4,5}", filename).group()}'): relist})


@oswalk_deco
def docname_format(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        content = re.sub(r'docname=".*"', f'docname="{filename}"', content)
        file.write(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        target_dir = '.'
    else:
        target_dir = sys.argv[1]

    regex_print('.*\.svg', 'docname=".*"')
    regex_print('.*\.svg', 'stroke:none')
    sub_string('.*\.svg', 'docname=".*"', 'docname="stackoverflow.svg')
```

It seems like I've missed some important properties in Python?

Comment: `for dir in subdirs: os.chdir(dir)` looks suspicious to me. If your initial current working directory is "C:\", and `subdirs` is ["foo", "bar"], then in the first iteration `chdir(dir)` will try to navigate to C:\foo. Then in the second iteration, `chdir(dir)` will try to navigate to C:\foo\bar instead of C:\bar. You need to chdir back up to your original current working directory at the end of each iteration.

Comment: ... But unless your program is crashing with a `FileNotFoundError`, that's probably not the root cause of your problem. Just something to watch out for.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake! It IS the reason of this problem and nothing to do with the decorators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `target_dir` defaults to `.`, the current working directory, if there's no command line argument given, and in your `wrapper` function, the `os.walk` function is always called with `target_dir`, which, after the `os.chdir` call, would refer to one of the subfolders of the first call to the decorated function, so `os.walk` naturally would not be able to find any more subfolders under `.`, which is already a subfolder.

You can fix this by getting the absolute path of `target_dir` first:

```
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    target_dir = '.'
else:
    target_dir = sys.argv[1]
target_dir = os.path.abspath(target_dir)
```